# Convert html.haml -> html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How would you convert this .html.haml file to .html.erb?

```
.rating-total{data: {id: @post.id, score: @avg_score || 0 }}
.total-score= @avg_score ? @avg_score.round(1) : 0
```

output in the browser should be something like this(e.g. 2 is post id):

```
<div class='rating-total' data-id='2' data-score='0'></div> 
<div class='total-score'>0.0</div>
```

---

I tried with this, but I don't get the proper output in the browser:

```
<div class="rating-total" data-id="#{@post.id}" data-score= "#{@avg_score || 0}"></div>
<div class="total-score">
  <%= @avg_score ? @avg_score.round(1) : 0 %>
</div>
```

output in the browser:

```
<div class="rating-total" data-id="#{@post.id}" data-score= "#{@avg_score || 0}"></div>
<div class="total-score">2.3</div>
```

Comment: What is your current output in the browser?

Comment: I tried different variations of code, but nothing outputs proper post.id and avg_score...I updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you shoudn't use the "#{}" but "<%= %>" instead. Try this:

```
<div class="rating-total" data-id= <%= @post.id %> data-score= <%= @avg_score || 0 %>></div>
<div class="total-score">
  <%= @avg_score ? @avg_score.round(1) : 0 %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

.rating-total{data: {id: @post.id, score: @avg_score || 0 }}
.total-score= @avg_score ? @avg_score.round(1) : 0

```
<div class="rating-total" data-id="#{@post.id}" data-score="#{@avg_score || 0}"></div>
<div class="total-score"><%= @avg_score ? @avg_score.round(1) : 0 %></div>
```

Your `total_score` is incorrect.

Comment: class name is irrelevant, this part is confusing: {data: {id: @ post.id, score: @ avg_score || 0 }}